# 404 error - Resource not found in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

I have registered a Bluemix account 10 days back and i tried to work tutorials.
upto yesterday the Bluemix was working fine, but today after successful login in, I am getting 404 error. I am able to see any pages, dashboard etc.

I have tried connecting eclipse to cloud foundry yesterday by installing bluemix plugin and enide plugin.What is the issue in Bluemix? Today Bluemix down? Or i have done anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluemix is currently experiencing issues in the US-South region. Here is some information on the outage:

> Some users are seeing 404 errors on there applications in US-South
>   Some users are experiencing 404 errors when accessing there
>   applications for longer periods then expected. This is due to an issue
>   during the planned maintenance of the US-South region. The team is
>   working on resolving this issue as fast as possible and we apologise
>   for any inconvenience caused.

You can see the current status of Bluemix issues here:

[Bluemix Support - View Status](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status)

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bluemix error, a downtime because of a problem started this morning. It is not a problem in your account; and Bluemix should be back up very soon!

*Update*: Bluemix is back to normal now, you should see your apps and services runnign again. Please comment otherwise!

Answer (score -1):

there is a problem with the platform announced at https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Update 2015-11-16 17:45 UTC: Applications which were experiencing 404 access errors during the maintenance period should now be running and operating normally.